# How to use Access-Control-Allow-Methods in header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache

When I set `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');` in my PHP header, I expect that I can't Post something to that file. But it isn`t like this. My firefox-browser shows the header in the console but do not act in any case. I expected an behavior like on Access-Control-Allow-Origin where the access will be denied.

```
var requestConfig = {
    url: "http://xyz.de/test7.php?",
    method: "POST",
    data: data
};
$.ajax(requestConfig)
```

This will be executed without any error.

Is Access-Control-Allow-Methods not supported or do I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from what I've read on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) is that, this header is for preflighted request. The browser will make an `OPTION` request to check what are the actual Methods accepted by the server and then do the request if it is an accepted method.

So you should send this header on the preflight `OPTION` request, **not** the actual `GET` request.

Comment: thre's no jquery example, as your problem relies on the server side.